# How to get the quantity of each ticket selected by the user and send that info to the payment page?

Tags: php, laravel

I have basketball match details page and a page to purchase a ticket. In the match details page, the user can select through a select option the type of tickets and how many of each one they want. And then click in "Buy" to go to the payment page. In the payment page I want to show a summary of what user selected, a summary like:

```
Type                 Quantity          Price         Subtotal
center                  2               100$            200$
left                    1               50$             50$
right                   1               50$             50$
Total                                                   300$
```

Do you know how to get the quantity of each ticket selected by the user in the match details page and send that information to the payment page to be possible to show the summary?

**Code structure that I have for this question:**

I have a FrontController and it has the single() method to show the match details page:

```
public function single($id){
        $match = Match::where('id', $id)->first();
        $tickets = Ticket::where('match_id', $match_id->id)->get();
        return view('matchs.show')->with('match',$match)->with('match', $match)->with('tickets', $tickets);
    }
```

Then in the match details page I have the types of tickets listed and for each one there is a select menu so the user can select how many tickets want for each one:

```
<ul>

    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <li>
            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 
            <form method="post" action="{{route('matchs.payment', ['id' => $match->id, 'slug' => $match->slug])}}">

                <select name={{ $ticket->title }}>
                    <option selected>0</option>
                     <option value="1">1</option>
                     <option value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>0.00€</span>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Payment Page"/>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Then there is also in the FrontController  the payment method to show the payment page (I dont know if this a good approach or if the payment() method should be in other controller, but for now is in the FrontController):

```
public function payment(){
    return view('matchs.payment');
}
```

The route to show the payment page:

```
Route::get('/match/{id}/{slug?}/payment', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@payment',
    'as'   =>'matchs.payment'
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your route from Route::get to Route::post in other way you get exception notMethodAllowed

Next: there will be probably an csrf exception - you need to add {{ csrf_field() }} into your form

I belive there is shorter and more elegant way to get one element from DB:

$match = Match::findOrFail($id) or you can even search for route-model binding

You can dispaly views with data in this shorter way: return view('matchs.show', compact('match', 'tickets'));

Basicaly you should get data inside payment() (it should be called store or something like that) and put that data into database or session and then redirect to the payment function with view where you retrive from session or DB that data from previous step

The way: single() -> submit form -> store(Request $request) -> save data and redirect -> payment()

Remember about validation all data from form.

Comment: Thanks, I add " {{ csrf_field() }}" but when the form button "Go to the payment page" is clicked the form is not submited, do you know why?

Comment: You have <form> opening tag inside foreach loop - So there is biiiig mess in HTML (many forms opening tags - but only one closing form tag)

Comment: Thanks, i change the form tag to above, and checked the source code, but the button still dont works.

Comment: There is </form> tag inside foreach loop too

Comment: Thanks, now its working, Im in doubt in this part relative to put the data in the session and  redirect to the payment.

Comment: In the payment method i can get the data, the dump is already showing the ticket type and the selected quantity. But then how to show that info in the payment page? That part I didnt understand. I need to redirect to a method that I also need to create in the Frontcontroller?

Comment: Basically my doubt is how to properly store the selected quantity in the session and redirect to the page again.